# Conditional Menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to show a WordPress menu based on the value of a cookie.
In my example, I'm using cookies to define the geographical region that the user wants to view. (I'm still working on this part so I'm manually defining it during development.)
Based on this, I want to use either menu1 or menu2.
Currently I'm using the following code:

```
function pstv_set_cookie() {
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    setcookie("region", "1", $expire);
}
add_action( 'init', 'pstv_set_cookie');

    if ($_COOKIE[$region] = "1"){ 
        //Use Menu 1
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu1' ));
        //wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu1' ) );

    }elseif ($_COOKIE[$region] = "2"){ 
        //Use Menu 2
        wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu2' ));
        //wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu2' ) );
    }
```

This works almost as expected, but it spits out the menu HTML before anything else.

Where do I add my coded to hook into the WordPress menu?

Note: I've tried:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu2' ));  AND
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu2' ) );
```

(I'm not too sure of the difference.)
Thanks in advance

Comment: if ($_COOKIE[$region] = "1") use double equals `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_nav_menu displays a navigation menu at the spot, you are using a init hook, that runs before anything else, like you figured.

Either:

- [run that code within the template between HTML](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Different_menus_for_logged-in_users)
- use a filter to [wp_nav_menu](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L145) (it has to be called somewhere)

Example for the filter (not tested):

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter');
function my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter($args = array()) {
  $args['menu'] = 'menu1';
  return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Only issue is that it affects my primary and secondary menu and replaces both with menu1. Will try and find a workaround

Comment: just make a conditional, if (args[menu] == menu1)

Comment: I tried this but it's not working... if ($args['menu'] == "menu1") {
   $args['menu'] = "menu2";} 
  return $args;

Comment: I managed to get this working using: if ( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' ) instead of if ($args['menu'] == "menu1")